# What is a good algorithm for mapping random (barcode values) numbers to an String in a collection?

Tags: java, algorithm, barcode

Say that my application has a finite number of "stuff", in my case they will be items in my game but for the purposes of this question I'll use Strings.

Say I have 5 Strings :

1. James
2. Dave
3. John
4. Steve
5. Jack

There will be a set list of them, however I will increase that list in the future.

**Question** : What is a good algorithm I can use, to go from a random number (generated from a barcode) into one of those values from above?

For example, if I have the value 4523542354254, then what algorithm could I use to map that onto `Dave`? If I have that same number again, I need to make sure it maps to `Dave` and not to something else each time.

One option I did consider was taking the last digit of the barcode and using the `0-9` that would map onto 10 items, but its not very future proof if I added an 11th item.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have a limit on how may strings you might end up with, or should it be dynamic?

Comment: Point of order!  Barcode numbers are not random numbers.  And numbers generated from barcode numbers aren't random either.

Comment: It should be dynamic. The app will start off with 10, but I will add more to that (potentially hundreds). This means that barcodes will offer a larger variety of `names`

Comment: @Stephen: `s/random/arbitrary/g`

Comment: @Steve - I'm not sure that's true.  If the number is generated from a bar code, it is not arbitrary either.  (The barcode may be, but the number isn't.)  And if you add in the possibility that the user can select the barcode ... or even create it him/herself, then the barcodes aren't arbitrary either.

Comment: This may seem to be pedantry, but if you use terms like "random" and "arbitrary" incorrectly in a technical context, people are liable to misinterpret you ... and indeed, you are liable to confuse yourself and make incorrect assumptions.

Comment: @Stephen C: I think I'm using "arbitrary" correctly. "Arbitrary" means it might be random, it might be controlled by some person somewhere, but the software that has to handle it has no control over it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the clarification that "If I have that same number again, I need to make sure it maps to Dave and not to something else each time." only applies as long as the set of strings doesn't change.

Simplest is what Maverik says, `name = names[barcode % names.length];`

A Java `long` is big enough to store any UPC barcode, `int` isn't, so I assume here `barcode` is a `long`. Note that the last digit of a UPC barcode is base-11, it can be `X`. I leave it as an exercise for the reader how you actually map barcodes to numbers. One option is just discard the check digit once you've established that it's correct - it's computed from the others, so it doesn't add any information or discriminate between any otherwise-equal codes.

But as Stephen C says, barcodes aren't random, so this might not give you a uniform distribution across the names.

To get a better distribution, you could first hash the barcode. For example `name = names[String.valueOf(barcode).hashCode() % names.length];`

This still might not be entirely uniform -- there are better but usually slower hash functions than `String.hashCode` -- but it probably avoids any major biases that there may be in real-life barcodes.

Also, I can't remember whether the Java modulus operator returns negative results for negative input - if so then you need to coerce it into a positive range:

```
int idx = String.valueOf(barcode).hashCode() % names.length;
if (idx < 0) idx += names.length;
```

Comment: If I add more Strings, I'm happy to scrap any previous mappings, does that alter your response?

Answer (score 5):

Hmm... If it is OK that multiple values can be mapped to the one, you can use

```
string name = names[value % number_of_names];
```

Comment: +1 - Simple solutions are best.  If it is "not OK", the question makes no sense ... unless you assume that there are only 5 barcodes / "random" numbers in the universe of this game.